# Setting permissions error in workflow

Tags: sharepoint-permissions

We have a workflow which sets permissions on the current item. three different permission levels are set for different user groups. This workflow has been working with no issues for 6 months but it is now failing with out any helpful error message. The list has over 10,000 records. Could this be the issue?

Comment: Please specify which workflow are you using? 2010 or 2013? If you get any error message or share the status of workflow, please share.

Comment: We are using 2013. Nintex has confirmed that we have exceeded the number of unique permissions that can be assigned to a list which is 10,000. Thanks